# Pipe multiple files as a single input into a program

Tags: python, terminal

I am stitching together a lot of TIF files (and I have multiple directories) using [AutoStitch](http://matthewalunbrown.com/autostitch/autostitch.html). I am currently doing this manually, which requires opening AutoStitch, then selecting multiple input images for the stitch and running AutoStitch, then saving the output and repeating for all of my directories. Obviously, I would like to automate the process. 
I am trying to write the code in python and so far I have started to write a code to automate the processing of a specific directory (I will try to write a loop when I get this to work):

```
import subprocess as sp 

command = "ls /Users/Annis/Desktop/K3.1_tsh2_antiLG2/1.5 | grep *.tif | open -f -a AutoStitch > output.tif"

print sp.check_output(command, shell=True)
```

But this just opens AutoStitch and doesn't seem to input the files. Can anyone help?

Comment: That `open` command makes me thing you're using OS X.  If that's the case, your pipeline isn't going to work...`open` doesn't do anything with stdin, because it's meant to open a GUI program.

Comment: I guess you want to use those .tif files as arguments to run AutoStitch?

Comment: Yes. The program requires 2 or more tif images to be opened to stitch them together.

Comment: @user9237776 try [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html): `grep *.tif | xargs open -f -a AutoStitch`